# How to customize arguments of the url of a Views page?

Tags: drupal, url, arguments, drupal-views, drupal-7

I'm building a site with Drupal 7.2 and Views 3.0, and 30+ useful modules. I know little about urls, arguments, PHP, SQL... The title of my question might be ambiguous, so here's the context:

For example, I've created a content type named "articles", and with Views, I've made a list of articles (or teaser), and set the url to `example.com/articles`.

I added a field named "type" (list, checkbox) to this content type, now I can enter Views-> Filter Criteria, and expose the "type", and configure arguments in "Filter identifier". and now I can get urls like this: `example.com/articles?type=type1`, `example.com/articles?type=type2`"...

But, I also want to make the url like this: **`example.com/articles?type=type1&display=list&sort=top-rated`**, I don't know how to set the pattern of display (list, grid..) and the pattern of sorting (hottest, latest, top-rated, most-commented...) in the urls as arguments. Are there any modules or methods that can help? Thanks everybody for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of an easy way to do this with your requirements.  The first thing that comes to mind is creating separate page views for each *type of sort* and putting that in the path for the page view.  I have also not heard of a way to set the display in the url other than having separate urls.

Comment: well, in D7, adding a sort criteria can only sort the content ascendingly or descendlingly according to some type, but it relies on some dropdown select box. I've found a useful discussion about this issue, but I still cannot figure it out. Here's the link: http://drupal.org/node/228510

Comment: @MessyCS ah ok, I missed that, so you want to be able to change _what_ the sort is through the url not just the sort _order_?  I don't think that is possible as of now, though you could possibly still make multiple "page views" with different paths each with a different sort/display type

Comment: Yeah, yeah, that's what I mean, I've tried to set each sort/display a different path. While in this case there're some influential factors for example, pager numbers. And, if each possibility has been set a path, I think it'll turn out to be a little complicated. Arguments in urls look beautiful and efficient, but it's really a headache to us developers...